# Does the level increase from Bracers of the Merciful Knight increase the number of rounds of Fast Healing for the Injured Mercy?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, class-feature, paladin, character-levels

I know that the Bracers of the Merciful Knight increase the base healing of Lay on Hands and the number of times per day that a Paladin can use it.

Do you also take the +4 levels into consideration for the number of rounds that Fast Healing is applied by the Injured Mercy?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: Thanks for the edit and tag assistance!

Comment: Glad to help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It says it treats your level as 4 higher for base healing and number of times per day you can use it. It doesn't mention effecting your mercies so I'd say no. However it does still seem to be a useful magic item even without boosting the mercy.

Answer (score -1):

## No, the Bracers have no effect on Mercies

The rules for the [Bracers of the Merciful Knight](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/a-b/bracers-of-the-merciful-knight/) only mention boosts to Lay On Hands. Nothing in the description mentions any changes to the [Mercy](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/Paladin/#TOC-Mercy-Su-) special ability. And, although Mercy itself depends on and seems like an extension to Lay On Hands, it is a separate class ability.

Comment: Other than the title and links, I don't see what new information this answer gives that @Kronos106's answer didn't already present us.

Comment: @ShadowKras I personally consider the differences enough to warrant a different answer. YMMV.